# Posting a picture on Facebook

Tags: c#, facebook, sdk

I'm new to C# Facebook SDK, so I want to know how things works. First, I want to know how to post a picture with description on Facebook page like `facebook.com/TennisHelper`.

The picture is of PNG format and I want it to be posted on the timeline wall.

Comment: Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361561/how-can-i-use-the-facebook-c-sharp-sdk-to-post-on-facebook-pages