# C# Facebook SDK: How to

Tags: c#, wpf, facebook, sdk, desktop

I have tried to find answers on following questions for at least one hour but with no success.
I have WPF project (C#) and I have webBrowser control to navigate to my Facebook page http://www.facebook.com/TennisHelper and I want to do next few things:

1. I want to avoid login by creating user settings in my application which will contain email and password, but I don't know how to do that with C# Facebook SDK,
2. I want to make able for my user to post textual posts on that page via textBox control,
3. I want to make able for my user to post photos from his computer directly to that page, but with not creating new albums. Just to post image on page wall.

I was searching Google for all those problems but with no success

Answer (score 0):

Let me know actually what is your requirement.I think your first requirement is to add a facebook login(or register with facebook page) button in your Website login page.

step1:You need to register a new facebook application on facebook.
step 2:install facebook c# sdk .You can either download the zip file manually or install it using nuget.I recommend the second option.I am using c# sdk 5.4.1 [What is nuget?](http://nuget.codeplex.com/) [How to install a package using nuget?](http://csharpsdk.org/) 
step 3:Now you can add name space facebook to the page
step 4:Insert a login button(simply a button with text login) in login page(say login.aspx).Let it be button1
step 5:On click button redire to another page (let  login1.aspx)
here is a sample code for login 1

using Facebook;//

```
  FacebookOAuthClient fb = new FacebookOAuthClient();
    UriBuilder red = new UriBuilder("www.example.com/Login1.aspx");
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string appid = "{your app id}";
        string appsecret = "{your app secret}";
        string permissions = "publish_stream";

       if(Request.QueryString["code"] == null)
        {

            try
            {

            Response.Redirect("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" + appid + "&redirect_uri=" + red.Uri.ToString() + "&scope=" + permissions +"&state=djfjfdjj");
            }
            catch (Exception b)
            {

                Label1.Text = b.ToString();
            }
            }
        else
        {
            try
            {

                FacebookOAuthClient cl = new FacebookOAuthClient();



                cl.RedirectUri = red.Uri;
                cl.AppId = appid;
                cl.AppSecret = appsecret;


             dynamic result = cl.ExchangeCodeForAccessToken(Request.QueryString["code"]);
                 Label1.Text = Convert.ToString(result);
              if (result["access_token"] != null)
                 {
                     Session["access_token"] = result["access_token"].ToString();//Now you have access token

                     Response.Redirect("Welcome.aspx");//replace welcome.aspx


                 }
                 else
                 {
                     Label1.Text = "Unable to authenticate\n Please try again later";
                 }
            }
            catch(Exception b)
            {
                Label1.Text = b.ToString();

            }
        }

    }
```

Now you have access token saved in session.

for getting basic information of the client

```
dynamic me=fb.Get("\me");
```

it in cludes first name, last name ,email address,location,image url etc. of the current user.Now you can use this e-mail or name to verify your user or register new user etc.(its up to you ).

posting on that page is possible but diffiult [How can I use the Facebook C# SDK to post on Facebook Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361561/how-can-i-use-the-facebook-c-sharp-sdk-to-post-on-facebook-pages)

Comment: why appid? my application is not facebook application, it is desktop application based on WPF

Answer (score 0):

You should register an application on Facebook in order to  use Facebook log in.navigate to
http://developers.facebook.com

create an appllication.You will get an application id and application secret.Use it as appid,appsecret