# How to post using PostTaskAsync in Facebook C# SDK?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, windows-phone-8.1, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm using the [Facebook C# SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Facebook/) to authorize my app login and post on the user's timeline. So far the login feature works and permissions are authorized, but when my code gets to the `PostTaskAsync` method, my app crashes with an error stating:

`The program '[1020] LC Points.WindowsPhone.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).`

I've been following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361561/how-can-i-use-the-facebook-c-sharp-sdk-to-post-on-facebook-pages?lq=1) on SO but their is no `Api` method available in the SDK I'm using.

Does anyone know how to debug or resolve this posting issue?

I've submitted the `publish_actions` for review on the Facebook developer console, but don't think that's the reason the app is crashing.

This is the ShareApp Task I'm using to call the login and posting code:

```
        private async Task ShareApp()
        {
            //Facebook app id
            var clientId = "573586446116744";
            //Facebook permissions
            var scope = "public_profile, email, publish_actions";
            var redirectUri = WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri().ToString();
            var fb = new FacebookClient();
            var app = new FacebookClient(fb.AccessToken);
            var loginUrl = fb.GetLoginUrl(new
            {
                client_id = clientId,
                redirect_uri = redirectUri,
                response_type = "token",
                scope = scope
            });

            Uri startUri = loginUrl;
            Uri endUri = new Uri(redirectUri, UriKind.Absolute);
            WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAndContinue(startUri, endUri, null, WebAuthenticationOptions.None);


            //Code to post app on the user's timeline after button click..crashes when program execution comes to this code:
            var postArgs = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            postArgs["link"] = "http://allaboutwindowsphone.com/software/developer/Brian-Varley.php";
            postArgs["name"] = "More from BV Apps..";
            postArgs["message"] = "I'm using LC Points to calculate my Leaving Cert Points!";
            await app.PostTaskAsync("/me/feed", postArgs);
            //app.Api("/me/feed", postArgs, HttpMethod.Post); //no Api method available which is why I've used PostTaskAsync instead.


        }
```

[This is the link to the repo on my GitHub for reference](https://github.com/BrianJVarley/LC_Points/blob/master/LC%20Points/LC%20Points.WindowsPhone/View/MainPage.xaml.cs)